# Angular 4 host header request not set

Tags: angular

I am trying to send a request to a server, and I want to change the host. The code is the following:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Host': 'www.test.com'});
    console.log(headers.get('Host'));

this.http.post("/test",headers);
```

The host is still localhost:8080. I am using Angular 4 and HttpClient.
 How can I set the host?

Comment: `this.http.post('http://www.test.com/test', data)`. Host s not a header. And the second argument of  post() is the body of the request, not the headers. Note that you won't be able to send anything to www.test.com unless they have allowed CORS request to theur server.

Comment: So how can I set the host then? Thanks.

Comment: I already answered that. Read my comment again.

Comment: @DenisaCorbu you can't manipulate host in angular. If you have CORS errors by local development, then you should change CORS setting on you server side. If you does't have access to server, then you can use following chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter should be data..Please try this.

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Host', 'www.test.com');
headers.append('X-SCOPE-ID', '27JM38');
this.http.post("/test",data,{headers: headers});
```